# Does Windows log program launches?

Tags: windows, logging, python, veracrypt

I wrote a Python script to automate mounting my Veracrypt-encrypted file.

The password is provided via standard input (without echoing).

```
os.system('veracrypt /hash whirlpool /l K /p "' + password + '" /v "C:\encrypted_file" /q /h n /s')
```

However, I am worried that Windows 10 might log this whole line, along with password plaintext for someone to find should my computer be stolen while it's running.

Does Windows 10 log program calls? If so, how can I prevent it?

Comment: Have you tried executing a unique command then searching the Windows partition to see if that string was logged?

Comment: @Daisetsu That wouldn't work if the data is encoded e.g. for a binary log.

Comment: @forest yep, that's certianly a possibility. But it doesn't hurt to check, it's not an exhaustive solution to check, but a potential first step (hence a comment, not an answer).  It's a good ovservation, I should have clarified my comment.

Comment: Looks like it's at least possible to intercept system calls https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15407154/keeping-a-log-of-system-calls